# Image of holomorphic function is nowhere dense

Tags: complex-analysis

As a preparation for my exam I'm going through some questions and I'm not sure how to approach this one.

**Show that the image of a holomorphic $f:\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$ is nowhere dense if $n<m$.**

The only intuition I have with this question is that the image $f(\mathbb{C}^n)$ will be a dense subset of dimension $n$ (possibly $<n$?) of $\mathbb{C}^m$, but because of the difference between dimensions it "won't be enough" (although I'm not going to lie, here I'm thinking about it in category of measures mostly). The other approach that I had in mind was to somehow relate $f(\mathbb{C}^n)$ with the zero set of this function (namely set of such $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$ where $f(z)=0$) since at least in one dimension zero set is nowhere dense, but this seems more wrong than the first approach.

Nevertheless, those ideas are by far too informal to talk about any kind of a solution, so I would really appreciate any help here.

Thanks!

Comment: The real question is what you can use to prove this. Your $f$ is in particular smooth as a map $\mathbb{R}^{2m}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ so you could apply (the weak version of) the Sard's theorem.

Comment: @carciofo21: I think that Sard's theorem alone is not enough to arrive at the conclusion since there are sets of measure zero which are dense nonetheless. Proofs I know of Sard's theorem do not tell us about the structure of the set of critical values, e.g. something like they lie in a positive codimension submanifold; only that they form a set of measure zero. In fact, there are examples of smooth maps $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ whose image is dense, so the complex structure is probably important here.

Comment: I remember this from Hirsch, but maybe I am misremembering.

Comment: Yes I was misremembering. This result has different formulations in different editions of his book. Beside, I suspect that in an older version Hirsch consdiered as nowhere dense sets what we more commonly call meager sets.